# Footer won't stay at bottom below content despite sticky footer

Tags: footer, sticky-footer

I can't seem to get the header and footer to span across a mobile device such as iPhone, and the footer won't stick to the bottom.  I've tried a meta code such as this:

My CSS mobile:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#logo {
left: 5%;   
}
#navMenu {
position: relative;
left: 5%;   
}
#content {
position: relative;
width: 95%;
height: 600px;
left: 2px;
right: 2px; 
}
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 5; 
}
```

I've added this to the HTML meta:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0,

Here is my desktop CSS incase something may override my mobile:

```
#header {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
z-index: 1;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.2);
background-color: rgba(234,234,234,1);  
}
#navMenu {
position: absolute;
left: 55%;
top: 55px;
width: 325px;
height: 39px;
z-index: 3;
}
#logo {
position: absolute;
left: 20%;
top: 95px;
width: 300px;
height: 85px;
z-index: 1;
}
#pageLocation {
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
top: 240px;
width: 69px;
height: 25px;
z-index: 5;
color: rgba(50,153,204,0.1);
}
#content {
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
top: 270px;
height: 600px;
width: 60%;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
z-index: 2;
border-bottom-color: rgba(50,153,204,0.2);
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: rgba(204,204,204,.1);
border-right-width: thin;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.2);
border-left-width: thin;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-color: rgba(50,153,204,0.2);    
box-shadow: 0px .5px .5px .5px #333;
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
alignment: center;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
z-index: 1;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #333;
background-color: rgba(204,204,204,.7);
}
```

I've tried sticky footer techniques with no luck.  I've gotten the footer with this method to stick to the bottom, but it just overlaps content when I scroll back up.  Please help, this is very frustrating to get a simple iPhone/android capable footer that sits at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Create a fiddle of your problem

Comment: You'll need to create a fiddle with the html and css. Just going off of your CSS it doesn't appear to follow any of the Sticky Footer CSS's I've used before. Start here for more tips. [Sticky Footer Explained](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) - | - [Another Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Comment: unfortunately those are the sources I used and they just made the layout even worse in appearance.